# what's the efficient way for making constant request to db via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a real-time chat app using php,mysql,jquery and ajax.

I wish to understand a better way of doing real-time task.
I wish to start checking for new messages, is user online and is user typing right after user logged in.

For now, **I make ajax call on setTimeout to db to get the data on document ready.** Is this a correct way? Or is there any other method which can improve system performance?

Also, I first retrieve an array of conversation id to check for. Then **I loop through the array to check if there's new message or if user typing**. I don't think this is efficient enough. One conversation has to be checked after another. Is there a way where I can fire seperate call to each conversation id provided in the array?

Now it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//check for new message on document ready
 if(localStorage.getItem("ckuser") > 0){
    var id;
    var friends;
    $.when(
           ckit.getConversation(),//get conversation ids
           id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ids')),
           ckit.getFriends(),//get friends
           friends = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('friends'))
    ).then(
           //new messages
           $.each(id, function(k, v){
            console.log('checking');
            ckit.check(v);
           }),

           //is online
           $.each(friends, function(k, v){
            ckit.isOnline(v);
           }),

           //is typing
            $.each(id, function(k, v){
                ckit.getIsTyping(v);
           })
    );

 }
}
```

This is how each checking for new message, user online and is typing looks like:

```
 $.when(
    [make ajax call for first time]

    ).then(
        (function callMe(){
            [make ajax call with updated lastupdate time]
        setTimeout(function(){
            callMe();
         }, 1000);


        })()
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way to do it will be using sockets. You can use library like socket.io for this purpose. Another option will be to use JSON long polling.

Since you are using PHP you can checkout [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/) (a library for php real-time apps using socket.io)

Socket.io uses the WebSockets to aid real-time communication. It also includes fall-back mechanisms that use traditional (long-)polling ajax requests.

Comment: could you provide me with good reference to these two technics please? Also I wonder, the socket, is it hosted in a third party server or simply library?

Comment: @arun: You are right. Sockets is the way to go. Please provide proper resources to advocate your answer. Otherwise, this could have been a comment as well.

Comment: @BhavikShah Thank you for the suggestion.  Updated with reference

Comment: @ArunGhosh, is node js is a must even though I work in php?

Comment: @Keren you need to have NodeJS.